# can't find the error

Tags: bibliographies

could somebody help me I can find the error

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,12pt]{elsarticle}

\journal{Int. J. Appl. Comput. Math}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}

%==========================================
\def\ds{\displaystyle}
\def\gr#1{\text{\bf #1}}

\DeclareSymbolFont{msbm}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\R}{\mathalpha}{msbm}{'122}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\N}{\mathalpha}{msbm}{'116}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rand}{rand}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pe}{Pe}

\def\rbf{RBF }

\newcommand{\bfx}{{\bf x}}
\newcommand{\bfv}{{\bf v}}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\bfX}{{\bf X}}

\def\RBF{RBF }
\newcommand{\I}{{\mathcal{I}_{i,m}}}
\newcommand{\Ic}{{I_{i+1/2,m}}}
\newcommand{\Iu}{{I_{i,m}}}


\newcommand{\mI}{{I_{i+1/2,m}}}
\newcommand{\hI}{{\widehat{I}_{i,m}}}


\newcommand{\Ip}{{I^+_{i,m}}}
\newcommand{\Imn}{{I^-_{i,m}}}

\parskip1ex plus1ex minus1ex
%==========================================


\begin{document}
All we know is limited, apart from knowing \cite{Micchelli} the answer we all know.Some people are too \cite{Hosseini}nosy. What can happen to them (figure \ref{s}) is described by Laura Lion~\auto{glass2012}.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Biblio}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Start by commenting out things that you think aren't causing the error, and see if the error remains.  Is the error in your bibliography?  You've not posted `Biblio.bib` for us to see.  Can you copy and paste the exact error message that TeX is telling you?

Comment: It looks like you are set up to use BibTeX, but `\citetitle` and `\autocite` are from the biblatex package.

Comment: Also (not related to the problem): you shouldn't be loading `epsfig`. It has been deprecated for more than 1/4 century. Load `graphicx` instead.

Comment: here is the error:  
INFO - This is Biber 2.14
INFO - Logfile is 'Manuscript.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'Manuscript.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Comment: I don't know how to upload the Biblio.bib.  And to refer the reference, I only use  \cite{} for all the document

Comment: as well as not using epsfig do not use `\bf` (it is not defined by default in latex) also note you are using psfrag so must use latex/dvips not pdflatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run `bibtex` and not `biber`. For `biber` you have to load package `biblatex` and `\addbibresource{}` and for the printed bibliography only `\printbibliography`